# Can TileMill be used to create Paper Map from OpenStreetMap source?

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, paper

I would like to know which software is the best for making paper map from osm source. Is tileMill good for that ?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Could you please explain your question detail ? and whats your objective ? (I am unclear   regarding your objective)

Comment: I want to create a city map from osm source. I want to get osm information in the software and edit it. For example all the buildings in black and all the main roads in red.

Answer (score 3):

You could use TileMill or even Mapnik but I personally would use QGIS.  QGIS has a good Map Composer specifically for creating paper maps.  It also has the ability to retrieve OSM data by area and so should provide everything you need in one package.